# Springboot conditional bean how to determine whether being run locally or not

Tags: java, spring

I need to create a conditional bean, which will be created if the application is run locally, ie on the developer computer. So say a conditional bean is created using:

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, 
                           AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return true; //some logic will be replacing this.
    }
}

@Bean
@Conditional(MyCondition.class)
public ObservationWebSocketClient observationWebSocketClient(){
    log.info("creating web socket connection...");
    return new ObservationWebSocketClient();
}
```

The goal is to make MyCondition be true when running for developer machine.

I can use Spring profile:

```
@Profile("local")
public ObservationWebSocketClient observationWebSocketClient(){
}
```

But that is not what will serve the purpose. I can run for different profiles such as dev/staging, etc not necessarily local profile only on the local/developer machine. So some sort of logic is required in MyCondition:

```
public class MyCondition implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, 
                           AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().equals("localhost");
    }
}
```

It's dummy logic but something like that which differentiates the current environment would be necessary.

The same code will run both on server and developer machine. When it is run on developer machine, it would be derived automatically that it is being run in developer machine.

The goal is to improve Developer Experience. Because many times it happened the developer set the profile as local and forgot to revert it and while deploying unnecessarily configuration specific to developer machine got included inadvertently that failed while running on server.

Comment: You can combine several Spring Profiles with each other, e.g. dev + developer-machine. And then you bind your special bean to the profile developer-machine. localhost as a condition will not work.

Comment: Why exactly will a profile not work? That's _precisely_ what I've been doing for several years (even named `local`).

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic, as already explained, I don't want to hard code "local". because the developer could run any profile - local, dev, staging in his local machine; not necessarily only local. I have updated the post accordingly for more clarification.

Comment: Improve the developer experience by relieving them of the responsibility of deploying applications directly from their local machine to the server. Instead, allow them to trigger a job in a continuous integration/continuous deployment system to do so with the correct configuration.

Comment: I agree with a previous commenter, profiles were created for exactly this reason.  One comment you made jumps out at me, that developers change the profile and forget to revert.  This speaks to some bigger, more fundamental, issues.  Consider a 12factor approach to your design, and externalize the config to the environment,  i.e. no configuration should be committed to your repository.